# Method onStartTrackingTouch and getProgress() of seekbar. First value is always 0.

Tags: java, android, seekbar

For a lock/unlock system I use the `onStartTrackingTouch` and `onStopTrackingTouch` methods. And testing, I don't understand one thing:

```
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

Log.d(TAG,"Progress: "+seekBar.getProgress());

    }
```

The first value is always zero.

Why? I need the real value!

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my idea, finally i've used onProgressChanged:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if(progress>95){
        seekBar.setVisibility(SeekBar.INVISIBLE);
                    //code

    }

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    seekBar.setProgress(0);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I use this method too, but just noticed that it allows the "slide" to unlock to start at the end of the slide.  Kinda defeats the purpose.  So you can just touch the end of your slide I bet to unlock instead of having to go through the whole slide action.  I am wishing onProgressChanged had a way to give intermediate values.  I'm going to look if I can somehow get the touch position in onStartTrackingTouch()